# C99 pointer to compound literal array of pointers

Tags: c, c99, compound-literals

NOTE: I am actively fiddling with this over on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/PD3nMH).

I have a (self-referential) structure:

```
typedef struct T_Function T_Function;
struct T_Function
{
    T_Function * (* inhibits)[]; // pointer to array of pointers to this structure
};
```

and would like to use compound literals as the target of the `inhibits` pointer.  Something along the lines of

```
T_Function a, b, c;
a.inhibits = & (<type>) {&b, &c};
```

This could be done as follows but I am looking to understand the type specification so I can use compound literals.

```
T_Function a, b, c;
T_Function * ai[] = {&b, &c};
a.inhibits = &ai;
```

**What is the appropriate type specification to replace `<type>` above?**

Answer (score 0):

`a.inhibits` is a pointer to some subsequent memory locations forming the pointer array.  If you want to assign something to `a.inhibits`, you need an array of pointers somewhere whose location to store in `a.inhibits`.  This is why there is no syntax like `&(...){&b, &c}`: it *can't* be right regardless of what you are using for `...` because there is no actual array `{&b, &c}` in the memory.

In your second example, you are allocating an array of `T_Function *` pointers on the stack.  This is a common programming error: `a.inhibits` will point to a location on the stack, and as soon as the current stack frame is left, the contents of `a.inhibits` will be undefined.  Still worse, *writing* to `a.inhibits` will cause undefined behavior.

You'll probably want to use a data structure of some kind, but to answer your question, the simplest solution would be to allocate the array on the heap:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct T_Function T_Function;
struct T_Function
{
    T_Function **inhibits;  /* no [] */
};
```

…

```
T_Function a, b, c;
T_Function **ai = calloc(2, sizeof(T_Function *));
ai[0] = &b;
ai[1] = &c;
a.inhibits = ai;
```

Just make sure you free the memory once you don't need it any more.

Comment: Thanks for trying to keep me on the right path with my memory usage though this was really just meant as a snippet.  You say that `&(...){&b, &c}` can't be right but I can do `int * (* not_typed)[4] = & (int *[]) {&one,&two,&three,&four};` (see http://ideone.com/PD3nMH for more).  Thanks to you sending me back to the basics I found the answer and will post it separately.

Comment: This won't do what you think it does, either. In this case, `one`, `two`, `three`, and `four` are global variables which means their address is known at linking time. If you try to do this inside a function, you'll run into the same problems as before.

Comment: I appreciate your concern for my memory usage and will be considerate and wary.  My only effort here was to learn the syntax for getting the address of a compound literal which is an array of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

`<type>` can be `T_Function *[]`.

```
typedef struct T_Function T_Function;
typedef T_Function * T_Inhibits[];

struct T_Function
{
    T_Inhibits * inhibitsTD; // pointer to array of pointers to this structure
    T_Function * (* inhibits)[]; // pointer to array of pointers to this structure
};

<snip>

T_Function x;
// direct
x.inhibitsTD = &(T_Function *[]) {&x};
x.inhibits = &(T_Function *[]) {&x};
// via typedef
x.inhibitsTD = &(T_Inhibits) {&x};
x.inhibits = &(T_Inhibits) {&x};
```

Do note that as @user3426575 pointed out, there are storage duration hazards with this.  Being a compound literal does not inherently imply static duration.

[C99 6.5.2.5-6](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf#page=88)

> The value of the compound literal is that of an unnamed object
>   initialized by the initializer list. If the compound literal occurs
>   outside the body of a function, the object has static storage
>   duration; otherwise, it has automatic storage duration associated with
>   the enclosing block.